# Getting "Data Not Available" Trying To Login from iOS Native App

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, login-errors

I'm developing a native iOS app using the Salesforce MobileSDK. It's been working fine, and then today I just get the following error when trying to login. It doesn't matter whether the login host is set to production, sandbox or custom (which is what I actually want).

[image: Data Not Available Error Page]

Anyone know how to fix this or is it a bug?

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce against Production or Sandbox.  Are you testing on device or simulator?  Incidentally, switching login hosts doesn't work at all on the simulator with 8.0, due to an Xcode 6 bug (still present as of 6.0.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with io8 and Salesforce. I'm seeing a similar issue with Salesforce1 and ios8 displaying visualforce pages. The entire page fails to render in that scenario.

Comment: Confirmed. This works in the 7.1 simulator (which can be done via Xcode prefs), but still doesn't in the 8.0 simulator.